# What's the solution to share information among the processors?

Tags: parallel-processing

I am writing a new algorithm for my [finite analysis code](http://foam.sourceforge.net/docs/cpp/a06514_source.html) using c++, suppose I am working on a 64*64 square mesh and it has four surfaces (surface A, B, C, D), and then I decompose it into four sub-domains, and it happens that the surface cells in surface A MAY also be scattered.

My question is kind of general, I am wondering if I want to calculate a variable in this 64*64 grids, but this variable depends on the ***entire*** surface A's coordinate information, then what should I do? Because I found that in some sub-domains, there is no A at all. So I found my code and new algorithm runs very well and successfully in serial, but it fails immediately in parallel.

Any advice or strategies for handling this kind of situation?

Comment: What kind of parallelization is being used? How was implemented?

Comment: I added a link to my finite analysis code. It shows the specific header file that is implementing the parallel computation.

Comment: Hey, downvoters, may I know what stackoverflow rule did I break, if you think it is too general, would you please suggest me how to rephrase it? thannnnnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel processing may be *tricky*, if you are using a algorithm based on [shared memory paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) you need to protect this memory region or you will have a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Other paradigms, like [distributed memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_memory), have other kind of strategies to handle this, mostly message passing.

Comment: As far as I understand, my code is using `distributed memory`

Comment: I'm not familiarized with OpenFOAM, but from the link you post it you are most likely dealing with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_processing) kind of paralellism, shared memory here is very implementation dependent